# JavaScript - Objetos

Tags: javascript

No console aparece 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Circulo is not defined at rascunho.html:9"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Objetos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        c = new Circulo(13, 11, 5);
        document.write('<p>Constructor: <pre>' + c.constructor + '</pre></p>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve definir primeiro `Circulo`. No momento em que você cria a instância de `Circulo`, ele está, naquele contexto, indefinido.

Você primeiro deve criar a sua classe:

```js
// Criando a classe:
function Circulo(p1, p2, p3) {
  this.p1 = p1;
  this.p2 = p2;
  this.p3 = p3;
  
  // ...
}

// Criando uma instância da classe
var c = new Circulo(1, 2, 3);
console.log(c.constructor);
```

#### Nota:

Se você estiver usando versões mais novas do JavaScript, você pode fazer assim:

```js
// Criando a classe:
class Circulo {
  constructor(p1, p2, p3) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    this.p3 = p3;
    
    // ...
  }
}

// Criando uma instância da classe
let c = new Circulo(1, 2, 3);
console.log(c.constructor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que definir o método construtor antes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Objetos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function Circulo (a, b, c) {
           this.a = a;
           this.b = b;
           this.c = c;
        }
        var c = new Circulo(13, 11, 5);
        document.write('<p>Constructor: <pre>' + c.constructor + '</pre></p>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```